# Using pthread in c++ to find max of array

Tags: c++

;I am trying to use the pthread.h library to find the minimum number from an array.  I am having trouble getting the code to compile and am unfamiliar with how to use pointers properly to make it work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
using namespace std;

int *min;
int *max;
double *average;
int n;

void* minimum(void* a){
  int size = n;
  int* array = (int*) a;
  int tempmin = array[0];
  for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
    if(array[i] < tempmin){
      tempmin = array[i];
    }
  }
  return NULL;
}

int main(){

int in;

cout << "How many numbers would you like to enter?" << endl;
cin >> n;
int numbers[n];
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
      cout << "enter number " << i+1 << endl;
      cin >> in;
      numbers[i] = in;
    }

pthread_t thread1;
int iret1

pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &minimum, (void*)numbers);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a thread? You can find the minimum number just iterating over the array in O(n) time.

Comment: What's the specific problem here?

Comment: I am trying to understand thread.h and want to create 3 separate threads for minimum, maximum, and average of an array

Comment: I get an error on line 11 at 
void *minimum((int*) a[]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming this is just an exercise, since there are better ways to achieve what you want. Please read [this link](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/). So here are some points to watch for:

1 - After pthread_create, you should call pthread_join to wait for it to complete and also to release its resources (you could also create a detached thread). You also need to pass the array to the thread as an argument:

```
pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &minimum, (void*)numbers);
pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
```

2 - The thread function receives a void*, so you need to cast it to whatever the argument really is:

```
void* minimum(void* a){
  int size = n;
  int* array = (int*) a;
  int tempmin = array[0];
  for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
    if(array[i] < tempmin){
      tempmin = array[i];
    }
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Yes I am just trying to familiarize myself with pthread.h. Your suggestion got rid of my error in the minimum function but now I am getting "undefined reference to `pthread_create'" when I go to compile. I have updated my code above.

Comment: Thank you that works great.  One more quick question, thought.  Is it possible to assign a value to global variables from inside the void functions?

Comment: Possible yes, but you need to watch out for concurrent access, since the variable could be modified from multiple threads concurrently. Next step in your study list are mutexes and semaphores.